# Flutter Test with easy_localization and big translation json file

Tags: flutter, localization, flutter-test, flutter-localizations

I'm using [easy_localization](https://pub.dev/packages/easy_localization) in a flutter project.
I need to write some widget tests.

But it looks like that when the `.json` file with the translations is too big, the `MaterialApp` never builds its `child` and therefore, I cannot test my widgets.

Here is the architecture of my small reproducible project:

```
my_project
 |- assets
 |   |- lang
 |   |   |- ru.json
 |   |   |- sv.json
 |- test
 |   |- test_test.dart
```

Here is my `test_test.dart` file:

```dart
import 'package:easy_localization/easy_localization.dart';
import 'package:easy_logger/easy_logger.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

void main() {
  testWidgets('', (tester) async {
    await tester.runAsync(() async {
      SharedPreferences.setMockInitialValues({});
      EasyLocalization.logger.enableLevels = <LevelMessages>[
        LevelMessages.error,
        LevelMessages.warning,
      ];
      await EasyLocalization.ensureInitialized();
      await tester.pumpWidget(
        EasyLocalization(
          supportedLocales: const [Locale('sv')],  // <- Change it to 'ru' and it doesn't work
          path: 'assets/lang',
          child: Builder(
            builder: (context) {
              print('builder1');
              return MaterialApp(
                locale: EasyLocalization.of(context).locale,
                supportedLocales: EasyLocalization.of(context).supportedLocales,
                localizationsDelegates: EasyLocalization.of(context).delegates,
                home: Builder(
                  builder: (context) {
                    print('builder2');
                    return const SizedBox.shrink();
                  },
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
      );
      await tester.pumpAndSettle();
    });
  });
}
```

`sv.json` (a small file):

```json
{
  "0": "0"
}
```

`ru.json` (a big file):

```json
{
  "0": "0 - xx ... xx",  // <- 1000 "x"
  "1": "1 - xx ... xx",  // <- 1000 "x"
  // ...
  "3998": "3998 - xx ... xx",  // <- 1000 "x"
  "3999": "3999 - xx ... xx"  // <- 1000 "x"
}
```

---

In my test, I have 2 `print`s which should respectively print `builder1` and `builder2`.

This works well when I use `Locale('sv')` in my test:

```
00:02 +0:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
builder1
builder2
00:02 +1: All tests passed!
```

But when I use `Locale('ru')`, `MaterialApp` doesn't build its child and I don't get the print `builder2`:

```
00:03 +0:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
builder1
00:03 +1: All tests passed!
```

---

How can I fix this?

Comment: Could you publish your repo so that we could clone it and reproduce the issue?
And which version of Flutter are you using?

Comment: It looks like it is a bug from the library. They are investigating it https://github.com/aissat/easy_localization/issues/409#issuecomment-886206258

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the end, I fixed it by adding a file `test/flutter_test_config.dart`. I got the inspiration from [this issue](https://github.com/aissat/easy_localization/issues/274#issuecomment-760167564).

```dart
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:easy_localization/src/localization.dart';
import 'package:easy_localization/src/translations.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';

Future<void> testExecutable(FutureOr<void> Function() testMain) async {
  final content = await File('assets/lang/sv.json').readAsString(); // <- Or `ru.json`
  final data = jsonDecode(content) as Map<String, dynamic>;

  // easy_localization works with a singleton instance internally. We abuse
  // this fact in tests and just let it load the English translations.
  // Therefore we don't need to deal with any wrapper widgets and
  // waiting/pumping in our widget tests.
  Localization.load(
    const Locale('en'),
    translations: Translations(data),
  );


  await testMain();
}
```

Comment: Can you show an example how you would use this?

Comment: Add this file "test/flutter_test_config.dart", then run the testWidgets() likes the questioner, the test passed on my side. If I want to test another language like French, I change "sv.json" to "fr.json" in this file, change " const Locale('en') " to " const Locale('fr')", then in testWidgets() will find the French text.

Answer (score 1):

This is because of how the json language file is loaded.
Take a look at this:

```dart
// from flutter/lib/src/services/asset_bundle.dart

Future<String> loadString(String key, { bool cache = true }) async {
    final ByteData data = await load(key);
    // Note: data has a non-nullable type, but might be null when running with
    // weak checking, so we need to null check it anyway (and ignore the warning
    // that the null-handling logic is dead code).
    if (data == null)
      throw FlutterError('Unable to load asset: $key'); // ignore: dead_code
    // 50 KB of data should take 2-3 ms to parse on a Moto G4, and about 400 μs
    // on a Pixel 4.
    if (data.lengthInBytes < 50 * 1024) {
      return utf8.decode(data.buffer.asUint8List());
    }
    // For strings larger than 50 KB, run the computation in an isolate to
    // avoid causing main thread jank.
    return compute(_utf8decode, data, debugLabel: 'UTF8 decode for "$key"');
}
```

If the file is bigger than a certain size, Flutter uses `compute` to load it and avoid UI jank.

If in your test, you add this line before the `await tester.pumpAndSettle()`, this will pause the main thread, give some time for the isolate to complete and resume execution.

```dart
await Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 150), () {}); // this line
await tester.pumpAndSettle()
```

On my laptop 150ms was the minimum duration to have the test pass consistently.

Answer (score 0):

When you are working with CodegenLoader this is a small method you can use to setup the easy localization singleton similar to the json example by Valentin Vignal, I would also suggest using small functions without callback parameters instead of nesting your setup functions, at least if you are not operating on the callback itself. This way it is clear that (only!) a side effect is happening.

```
void addLocalization() {
  Localization.load(
    const Locale('en'),
    translations: Translations(CodegenLoader.en),
  );
}
```